# cherrypy.request.body.read() unable handling Windows line breaks?

Tags: python, cherrypy

I have a file with the following content:

```
foo,foo,foo,^Mbar,bar,bar,
```

(vim representation, ^M is a Windows line break)

Submitting the file to cherrypy and reading it (*cherrypy.request.body.read()*) afterwards only prints *bar,bar,bar*

Shouldn't this print the whole file or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please post the whole cherrypy code (minimum amount of it to reproduce your behavior). 
Also post/describe the way you submit your file.

Comment: My bad, print wasn't printing properly. CherryPy handled it properly.